# How can I create a simple leveling up system?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a simple leveling up system, Where if I have enough of %experience% I will be able to gain %level%, my current code is

```
Set /a experience = %experience%+1
echo you gained 1 xp!
goto play
```

Play is where you type to get 1 xp so I shouldn't need to add that. I have tried looking around but I cannot find a answer so I decided to ask.

Edit: I'll add all the code

```
set /a experience = %experience%+1

:play
cls
echo               Options
echo          Current Level: %level%
echo          Current Xp: %experience%
echo Get xp
echo Level up
set /p ans="Choose : "

if %ans%==xp (
goto train
)

if %ams%==level(
goto levelup
)


:levelup
if %experience% GEQ 10 (
set /a level+=1
(
goto play

:train
cls
Set /a experience = %experience%+1
echo you gained 1 experience
goto play
```

Comment: `if %experience% geq 20 set /a level+=1`?

Comment: I did run help I just had trouble understanding, also @Stephan I do that but when I put the code in and make it goto play, I run the batch and it just crashers as soon as I want to level up.

Comment: Batch scripts don't crash. They might stop at severe syntax errors, but they don't crash. Don't run them via double-click. Open a cmd window and run them from there (at least for testing/troubleshooting). The window will then stay open and you are able to read any errormessages (which usually are very helpful)

Comment: It says the syntax of the command is incorrect.

Comment: I have found that [SS64 on Batch](https://ss64.com/nt/) is an excellent resource on Windows Batch Language. Consider bookmarking it and referring to it often.

Comment: I'd like to tell you what's wrong, but that is hard without seeing your code. Please edit your question with your new code.

Comment: fixed my code, @JeffZeitlin Ok I'll do that next time and if I can't figure it out I'll come here. Same with help command in cmd

Comment: simple typo: `if %ams%==level(` - your variable is `%ans%`. And be careful with spaces: `if %ans%==level (`

Comment: It still seems to close, I will check cmd again

Comment: Ok so now when I choose level it just cd's back to the folder the bat is in, so no syntax error just a close

Comment: The line after the "syntax error" messages shows the command as it is actually executed by the parser. What does it tell?

Comment: Duh - wrong parenthese. It should be a *closing* one after `set /a level+=1`

Comment: oh, Ill try to fix again

Comment: There is one, its just one row down, do I move it up to the same row?

Comment: oh, it worked thank you very much I have been stumped for a couple of days

Comment: does not need to be on the same line. The code in your question currently shows a wrong paranthese (a correct opening `(` after the `if` and a wrong one `(` which should be a `)` to close the `if` block.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:

```
:levelup
if %experience% GEQ 10 (
    set /a level=level+1
)
goto :play
```

Note that the above code was tested using `wine-5.0` on Linux Mint.

Hope this helps.